# Which future type (simple-vs-perfect) is correct for talking about an event that’s done?

Tags: grammaticality, future, perfect-aspect, future-perfect, will-future

> Graduated, I started attending the degree course in Computer Science and Engineering in 2017, where I **will** graduate after two years with ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀.

Is a simple *will graduate* ok here, or should I instead use the longer *will have graduated* perfect form?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by using *will* at all for the second clause's verb? How exactly would you say this in your native language, whatever that is? By your name I take you to be any of Italian, Spanish, or Portuguese, but when I think about how to say what you're trying to say in each of those three possible languages, I almost never come up with any sort of future tense for the second verb.

Comment: Do you mean something in English that could be expressed as *“In 2017 I began studying the degree course in Computer Science and Engineering, which I completed two years later with ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀”*? Or are you trying to realize a sort of "future in past" narrative sense, perhaps more like  *“I started attending the degree course in Computer Science and Engineering in 2017, from which I would graduate after two years with ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀”* might run in English?  I would love it if you could please post how you would say what you want to say in whichever of Italian or Spanish or Portuguese that you know best!

Comment: Like code, make things declarative and in order. "I will graduate early with a CS degree after only 2 years, and with a 98/110 grade."

Comment: What @tchrist said. It's 2020 now, but presumably a 2-year course started in 2017 ***would have finished*** in 2019, so it should be referenced using Past Tense ***would** graduate* rather than ***will** graduate*. (or the more complex ***will have graduated***, which is still a "future" reference, not appropriate if you've ***already*** graduated, as an established fact).

Comment: Where I am set to graduate after (only?) two years with 98/110.   Note that the way your score/GPA is treated is odd in English. Normally it would be preceded with something like “with a score of” or “with a GPA of” or even just “with a 98/110”   i’ll also note that I am unfamiliar with scores in a fractional format like that.

Answer (score -1):

The given sentence quite liberally teeters between tenses, and is erroneous. The first sentence seems like the narrator is limning in the past, and then fast-forwards to the present. I'd first rephrase the sentence as:

> Graduated, I started attending the degree course in Computer Science and Engineering in 2017, **after whose completion**, I will graduate **in** two years with ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀.

Now, to answer your original question, both *will graduate* and *will have graduated* are grammatical. But I'd go with the latter, as you have also specified a certainty of ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀. Hence, by using *will have*, you denote that you have prepared enough to obtain ⁹⁸⁄₁₁₀.

Comment: But 2019 is already in the past.

Comment: @tchrist What if this passage was written before 2019? The last sentence says that '...I will', implying that it was written before 2019 finished.